# How to I unlock Death Wish?

Tags: a-hat-in-time

I downloaded the Hat in Time DLC recently, but I do not have access to the Death Wish mode. I have beaten all of the boss battles

> except for the Conductor, but I did battle DJ Grooves.

What must I do to unlock Death Wish?

> The wiki said that I must beat all of the bosses to unlock Death Wish, but unless DJ Grooves and the Conductor count as different bosses, then I have beaten them all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Steam store page for the DLC](https://store.steampowered.com/app/787340/A_Hat_in_Time__Seal_the_Deal/), Death Wish also requires 27 Time Pieces.

If you are eligible, you should get an "Intruder Alert" cutscene either when you start the game (if you already have 27) or after you collect the Time Piece, showing you Snatcher sitting by the edge of the ball pit.

You should also be able to access the Death Wish map menu from the pause menu.

Comment: Oh, really? I did not check the Store Page, I did not expect it to have the answer lol.